# How can I get the name of a logged in user from a database?

Tags: sql, oracle

More specifically an Oracle database. Say I am logged in as `foo`. How do I get the name?

Also does this pose a security risk if the name is exposed to someone?

Comment: Do you mean `foo` is the Database user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user, uid FROM dual
```

From http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/z.dir/tip492545/oracle

(First google hit on "oracle whoami")

Answer (score 1):

in sqlplus you can just type

```
show user
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
SELECT * from user_users
```

I'd personally probably use the `USER` function (as stated by Stefan in one of the other answers) by using `select user from dual` or something similar but it's good to have other options.